# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () laravel cpanel

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I uploaded my laravel project on cpanel but when i try to access it shows me that error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
```

My cpanel directory is like that

```
-public_html
  -projects
    -project1
      -all files of public folder
      -project_name
        -all code
```

My index file is like that

```
require __DIR__.'/project_name/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/project_name/bootstrap/app.php';
```

My php version is 7.2 .
Don't know what am I missing?

And I try to access my project like that

```
mydomain.com/projects/project1
```

Comment: please check your server php version and your project php version

Comment: on server php version is 5.6 but when i changed it to 7.2 it shows me that error "base64_decode() has been disabled for security reasons"

Comment: @alex roger if you need that i think you could enable it in php.in https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2331/How-to-EnableorDisable-PHP-Extensions-From-cPanel.html ...And change it to base64_decode = On